# 'if' statements not behaving as expected without 'else'

Tags: c, if-statement

Just a quick question; I've been working through K&R and the code for the digit/whitespace/other counter works fine. However, whilst trying to get my head round the functionality of `else` I've encountered something which doesn't work as expected.

The code from the book is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

     printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

If I then modify the `while` loop so it reads:

```
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                ++ndigit[c-'0'];
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                ++nwhite;
```

It should still have the same functionality as the original code except for the fact it won't count 'other' characters. However what I actually get is in fact just the 'digit' part working, with 'nwhite' returning zero no matter what the input. I feel the disparity is perhaps due to a fundamental misunderstanding of how `if` statements function.

Comment: You need braces.

Comment: Note that many people always write `while (expression) { statement; ... }` using braces to avoid exactly this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
```

Is equivalent to

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
}
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        ++nwhite;
```

Only the first statement that follows a looping or branch construct "belongs" to that construct. That is why the original if-else if-else chain works without braces. Each statement chains to the previous with the first if/else statement belonging to the while loop and the second if/else belonging to the first if/else. It is idiomatic to express the logic this way to avoid unnecessary indenting.

It may help to visualize the code with braces

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    }
    else {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            ++nwhite;
        }
        else {
            ++nother;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
```

The second `if` statement is no longer in the loop. Use `{` and `}` to enclose the loop statements.